# Xcode: sigabrt error

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt, lldb

Im new to iOS programming and I'm trying to get the table view running with my app but I can't find any solid information as to why the app keeps aborting. here is the code from the delegate file, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong thats causing the error?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    listTopics = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:8];
    Topics *topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Movies";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Games";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"TV";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Cars";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Actors";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Sports";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Brands";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];
    topic.topic = @"Music";
    [listTopics addObject:topic];
    topic = [[Topics alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;      
    TopicsViewController *topicsViewController = [[navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0];
    topicsViewController.listTopics = listTopics;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: First of all: where is your TableView? Second: what is "listTopics"? Where is declared?

Comment: listTopics is in @implementation and the TableView I'm not really sure how to work with. I have been following the tutorial on this site: raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

if I am honest, I have not found any good, straight forward tutorials or anything for beginners on iOS development unlike android. Is there any good websites where there are tutorials that show basics and teach basics and work up from there?

Comment: yes it compiles just during runtime is the sigabrt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to show a navigation controller which has table view controller as a root view controller, which is TopicsViewController for you.

In your

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

method you need to set the rootViewController property of your window. You can not get it because you havent set yet. After that you need to make it visible. The following code should help you

```
TopicsViewController *topicsViewController = [[TopicsViewController alloc] init]; 
// or 
TopicsViewController *topicsViewController = [[TopicsViewController alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
// depends if it is a view controller or table view controller

topicsViewController.listTopics = listTopics;

UINavigationController *topicsNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:topicsViewController];
self.window.rootViewController = topicsNavController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

please note that, if you do not use ARC you need to release the objects you have called alloc on them.

Comment: ooo that did get ride of the error using the first version of TopicsViewController you showed me, bu it seems like the list is invisible even though i have the line [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; thanks for all the help  by the way to everyone

Comment: oh i just noticed sorry, the controller should be the table view not just view, so i will have to use the initWithStyle, but for some reason when i put this in it does not seem to be a pre made method

Comment: Does your TopicsViewController class extend from UITableViewController or a UIViewController? If it is UIViewController then you have to place your table view your self, other wise it is already placed.

Answer (score 3):

To help with debugging you should add an 'exception breakpoint'.
Go to the breakpoint navigator (one of the tabs on the left panel) and click the tiny + button at the bottom left. Choose 'Add Exception Breakpoint', then click ok.

Run the app again, and you should get a breakpoint at the line of your error.

Comment: thanks that worked and showed me where the error mainly occurs

Comment: @MakarEmelyanov: please make sure you accept this answer if it helped you - so others will know the topic is closed

Comment: i will but i still have one more problem, don't worry :)

Comment: .. one little thing, it's worth setting the exception breakpoint to only Objective-C exceptions if you're using third-party libraries that include C++ (like ZXing) or you'll find your app constantly stopping on C++ exceptions that end up being caught elsewhere (and thus don't 'matter')

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess  : your topicViewController is nil or is not a TopicViewController.

You may also have some memory issues as you are not releasing the objects you are creating. (or you are using ARC?). 
You may also check hos you are destroying your topics objects.

Please provide some more code for us to help you.

Regards

Comment: anytime i try release data it gives me an error so i am assuming that its cause i have ARC on

Comment: Well, that would depend of the error message. If you have ARC on you should have an error saying something like : ARC forbids explicit message 'release' or release is not available in automatic reference counting mode/.

Comment: just checked there i definitely have ARC on

Comment: Have you checked the value of your topicViewController ?

Comment: im pretty sure after doing some checks that it returns a null, any reasons why?

Comment: You don't seem to have pushed your controller, so it cant' be in your navigation controller.